# Javascript Valuable Webpage Data

Tags: xss, cookies

When malicious users and attackers seek to steal data using XSS, they can send attributes like document.cookie to a malicious server, correct?  Does this attribute have all of a users cookies for a particular website or just one for the specific site the page has visited?

If writing a blacklist, what other attributes can an attacker find valuable besides page cookies?

Comment: You should not create a blacklist but sanitize all user supplied inputs to prevent XSS

Comment: How can you sanitize reflected XSS?  If someone sends a link with added javascript to execute client-side, is there anyway to prevent this type of attack?

Comment: You can prevent this by writing good code which prevents this. Just escape and sanitize every user supplied value.

Comment: It depends on the website or app where the JavaScript is executed. They have to fix this in their code. The code has to run in the right context. If you want to steal cookies from website A, the attacker has to send the victim on website A a code which uses an XSS vulnerability in website A. But it can not access data from other websites opened in the browser. Just to make it clear, any userinput which is executed and not sanitized is dangerous. Think about eval(), XHR and so on. You could also send malware, run DDoS attacks and do much more with XSS.

Comment: Blacklisting specific words does not solve this. Any code on the website be it JavaScript or PHP has to sanitize and escape every userinput.

Comment: Is every website by default vulnerable to reflected xss by default then?

Comment: No, they are not by default.

Comment: If I had a website that only used Jquery to have dynamic scrollspy and affix sidebar, would this be vulnerable to reflected XSS, because you simply stamp the code into a url and the site has no ability to sanitize that?

Comment: Not if there is no XSS vulnerability. But you can still always sanitize and customize the codeto prevent any potential XSS, even with these libraries.

Comment: @thatguylowjwj I would recommend you to do some research on your own regarding what an XSS attack actually is. You seem to have various misconceptions and knowledge gaps which do not yet make you qualified to undertake the project you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, why does it matter if the website is vulnerable or not considering reflected xss has malicious code in the url which is run in the victims browser?  Does it have to go between the server first?  Can't you append malicious code to any link for the same affect?

Comment: @thatguylowjwj Malicious code in the URL is not executed by the victims browser by default. It only gets executed if the website takes information from the URL and embeds it into the website. Like for example a 404 error page which tells the user which url they tried to request. When part of the url happens to be valid HTML and the website doesn't sanitize it, the browser might interprete it as HTML. When that HTML also embeds javascript, that javascript can get executed. Example: `https://example.com/<script>alert('hello world');</script>` (doesn't work because example.com is not vulnerable).

Comment: Sample webapps like webgoat and damn vulnerable webapp are good learning tools

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case it would only have the cookie data of the website.

The idea of an XSS attack is to get a website the attacker does not control to embed arbitrary Javascript code in a way that when a user opens the website that Javascript is executed by their web browser as if it were normal Javascript embedded in the website. This can be used to gain access to any data which is available to Javascript executed on that website. Javascript can only access the cookie data of the domain it is executed on (and only those which do not have the http-only flag set). It is not possible to use Javascript alone to obtain cookie data from a different domain.

Regarding what other data an XSS attack can find: It can read the content of the HTML document it is executed on. So when the html document with an XSS vulnerability also includes any other personal information, that information can be extracted and sent to the attacker.